# Definition of k-edge-connected

Tags: graph-theory

The definition of "k-edge-connectivity" and "k-edge-connected" are as follows:

from wikipedia,

a connected graph is k-edge-connected if it remains connected whenever fewer than k edges are removed.
The edge-connectivity of a graph is the largest k for which the graph is k-edge-connected.

And then,

If a graph has a property of k-edge-connectivity, is it possible to call the graph 1-edge-connected, 2-edge-connected, ..., k-edge connected? or only k-edge-connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a graph $G$ is $k$-edge-connected, then $G$ is also $\ell$-edge-connected for every $\ell \leq k$.